# matomo SecurityInfo plugin privileged user error

Tags: php, linux, matomo

I installed the matomo  SecurityInfo plugin and I am getting these errors in red. What I don't understand is that I am already running php as a non privileged user and group. ( www-data for both user and group ) So why I still having this message ? Thank you

```
group_id    PHP may be executing as a "privileged" group, which could be a serious security vulnerability.
user_id PHP may be executing as a "privileged" user, which could be a serious security vulnerability.
```

Comment: Your www-data user are sudoers ?

Comment: www-data is not in sudores file. 
This is the content of passwd
www-data:x:33:33:www-data:/var/www:/usr/sbin/nologin

Comment: Keep in mind that this plugin uses a very old library for generating the tips, so take them with a grain of salt.

Answer (score 2):

[The test](https://github.com/matomo-org/plugin-SecurityInfo/blob/4.x-dev/PhpSecInfo/Test/Core/uid.php) only checks the group user ID of the user that is running PHP (`www-data` in your case) and throws a warning if it is below 100 (same for group id).

On my system the id of `www-data` is 33, therefore the library throws a warning.

As this seems to be the default in Debian (and therefore Ubuntu), I think that should be fine.